# Could an analysis of GPT4's WAIS score be published?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, chatgpt, large-language-models, gpt

Similar to this: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/i-gave-chatgpt-an-iq-test-heres-what-i-discovered/

But more detailed and in depth (subtest breakdown, including image analysis, etc.), WAIS-IV not WAIS-III, better methodology, etc.

Would it be a more interesting paper if it compared overall test scores and subtest scores to other LLMs, like 3.5, LLaMA, Mistral, etc.?

I know it's out of the box so I'm wondering if this is publishable in some journal. It seems that the WAIS interesting as there is both good human benchmark data, and it's never been on the internet, so there is no leakage.